# Add to script comfirmation for nohup ... & with enter

Tags: shell, nohup

This is the script.sh:

```
nohup myInnerScript.sh > LOG.log &
```

which I run like this

```
sh script.sh
```

after execution it waits to confirm with enter. How to add the confirmation? Something like this:

```
sh script.sh
<enter>
```

Comment: Why not remove the confirmation from the script?

Comment: because it is not mine

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
echo "" | sh script.sh
```

By default echo adds new line symbol at the end of the string - which is basically what you need.

Comment: what if I got `sh script.sh && sh.script2.sh` then `echo "" | sh script.sh && sh script.sh` will not resolve the problem...

Comment: If confirmation is in script.sh then it will work. If confirmation is in script2.sh then it should be: `sh script.sh && echo "" | sh script2.sh`

Comment: confirmation is in all scripts

Comment: then you have to pipe echo to all scripts